# Можно ли в цикле for задать ссылку на объект вместо массива данных?

Tags: java, ооп

В классе Professor должна быть вероятность провести перекличку нескольких групп из других классов. Хочу поинтересоваться как это можно сделать корректно? Выложил код двух классов, хотя их три. Надеюсь, этого достаточно.

```
public class Professor extends Group {
    Professor(Students[] studentsList) {
        super(studentsList);
    }

    @Override
    public Group process() {
        System.out.println("Проверка присутствия студентов:");
        for (Students st : getStudentsInGroup()) {
            switch (st.getCall()) {
                case " ":
                    System.out.println("Студент " + st.getStudentName() + " - отсутствует");
                    break;
                case "V":
                    System.out.println("Студент " + st.getStudentName() + " - присустствует");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Students{

    private String StudentName;
    private String CandidatName;
    private String Call;

    public String getCall() {
        return Call;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return StudentName;
    }

    public String getCandidatName() {
        return CandidatName;
    }

    Students(String studentName, String candidatName, String call) {
        this.StudentName = studentName;
        this.CandidatName = candidatName;
        this.Call = call;
    }

    static Students[] students = {
            new Students("Ануфриев Владимир", "Бевський Максим", "V"),
            new Students("Бевский Максим", "Ануфриев Владимир", "V"),
            new Students("Войтович Степан", "Бевский Максим", " "),
            new Students("Годун Александр", "Ануфриев Владимир", "V"),
            new Students("Дмитренко Степан", "Ануфриев Владимир", "V"),
            new Students("Ермолаев Иван", "Ануфриев Владимир", " "),
            new Students("Евсиков Игорь", "Бевский Максим", " "),
            new Students("Жебрак Алексей", "Бевский Максим", "V"),
            new Students("Забой Максим", "Ануфриев Владимир", "V"),
            new Students("Записоцкий Дмитрий", "Ануфриев Владимир", "V")
    };
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код. Непонятно что вы хотите.

Comment: Такой вопрос, а зачем вам static массив студентов? Как я понял, у вас есть три сущности: студент, группа и профессор. Профессор может проверить присутствие студентов нескольких групп? Верно?

Comment: Да. Замечание было в том, что метод класса Профессор проверяет массив, а не группу. И теоретически он должен проверять несколько групп. static может и не нужен, но классы Group и Professor пользуются массивом класса Students, а по-другому пока не знаю как его сделать общедоступным.

Comment: А как так получилось, что профессор наследует группу?) Чисто по логике, должно быть так: в группе могут состоять множество студентов, у профессора есть функция проверить присутствие, которая принимает переменное число групп. В этой функции вы перебираете всех студентов со всех групп.

Comment: Ну, на данном этапе я понимаю, что Профессор может наследовать только один класс, что не позволяет проверить несколько групп... А как можно реализовать переменное число групп для функции проверки присутствия? Как это хотя бы приблизительно выглядит?

Comment: т.е. получается, с Вашей логики, группа может быть родителем профессора (возьмите пример из реальной жизни) ?:) Я веду к тому, что вам стоит пересмотреть проектирование вашей программы.

Comment: хотел реализовать все принципы ООП в одной программе и это мне показалось удобным, потому что профессор заглядывает в журнал со списком студентов, а студенты к профессору никак не могут заглянуть без его разрешения. Может Вы и правы.

Comment: Добавил пример. Посмотрите. Создаете Lesson, передаете туда массив групп со студентами, создаете Teacher и вызываете свою функцию (передаете туда ссылку на ваше занятие)

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте архитектуру вашего приложения, например, так.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student("Петров Иван Иванович", "Петров Юрий Петрович", true);
    Group group = new Group("101-M", new Student[] { student });
    Lesson myLesson = new Lesson(new Group[] { group });

    Professor professor = new Professor();
    professor.checkPresence(myLesson);
  }
}

public class Student
{
  private String _studentName;
  private String _candidatName;
  private boolean _isPresent;

  public boolean isPresent() {
    return _isPresent;
  }

  public String getStudentName() {
    return _studentName;
  }

  public String getCandidatName() {
    return _candidatName;
  }

  Student(String studentName, String candidatName, boolean isPresent) {
    this._studentName = studentName;
    this._candidatName = candidatName;
    this._isPresent = isPresent;
  }
}

public class Group
{
  private String _groupNumber;
  private Student[] _students;

  public String getGroupNumber() {
    return _groupNumber;
  }

   public Student[] getStudents() {
    return _students;
  }

  Group(String groupNumber, Student[] students) {
    this._groupNumber = groupNumber;
    this._students = students;
  }
}

public class Professor
{
  Professor() { }

  public void checkPresence(Lesson lesson) {
    System.out.println("Проверка присутствия студентов:");

    for(Group group : lesson.getGroups()) {
      for(Student student : group.getStudents()) {
        if(student.isPresent())
          System.out.println("Студент " + student.getStudentName() + " из группы " + group.getGroupNumber() + " присутствует");
        else
          System.out.println("Студент " + student.getStudentName() + " из группы " + group.getGroupNumber() + " отсутствует. К сожалению:(");
      }
    }
  }
}

public class Lesson
{
  private Group[] _groups;

  public Group[] getGroups() {
    return _groups;
  }

  Lesson(Group[] groups)
  {
    this._groups = groups;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает только в методе main нужно прописать Group group = new Group("101-M", Students.students ); Иначе ругается

Comment: @Никита, там же передается массив (правда только 1 студент). Все должно быть отлично. Класс Student не должен знать сколько, какие студенты созданы и тем более не должен быть контейнером для студентов :)

Comment: Но тем не менее фигурные скобки в той строчке IntelijIdea не приемлет, а все остальное вообще отлично. Осталось только понять смысл этой строчки Lesson myLesson = new Lesson(new Group[] { group }); Для меня это что-то новое

Comment: @Никита, тут я могу посоветовать только учить :)

Comment: Не, я понимаю, что в объекте Lesson создается объект Group с массивом. Мне пока только не понятно как это связано с остальным кодом. Но ничего, поэкспериментирую и пойму) Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Никита, пожалуйста.

Comment: класс Lesson оказался лишним